# python load modules of same package structure found in different folders

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following folder structure:

```
data_plugin_main/
            /common
                __init__.py
                utils.py
            /data
                __init__.py
                commmon_dal.py


plugin1
            /data
                __init__.py
                data_plugin_dal.py      

plugin2
            /data
                __init__.py
                another_plugin_dal.py
```

I need to maintain this structure, but be able to write code that either imports or can reference:

- data.common_dal
- data.data_plugin_dal
- data.another_plugin_dal

It seems like python will only import/load modules in the first data folder it encounters.  so in above case, since there is in `__init__.py` under `data_plugin_main/data/`, `common_dal.py` is loaded.  however, even if I add the other paths to the `PYTHONPATH`,  `data_plugin_dal` and `another_plugin_dal` are not able to be imported or referenced.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using namespace-packaging:  https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Answer (score 0):

If I’m understanding correctly, you may want to try Pydev environment installed freely in Eclipse.

Each module is also the directory name with a parent module that fathers them all, so in pydev if plugin_2  source needs to reference common_dal.py the import looks like `from data_plugin_main import data.common_dal` 
So in the project explorer you would create a parent module That acts as a super `__init__` and then you can create child modules as you wish.  It’s kinda Javaishly inspired.